# Is there any way to use neo4django with django 2.0.1?

Tags: python, django, neo4j, neo4django

I have installed django 2.0.1, but when I install neo4django, it deinstalls that version and installs django 1.5.12.

is there any way to prevent so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [neo4django repository](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django) hasn't been updated in years.

The [requirements file](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/blob/master/requirements.txt) shows that it doesn't support Django 1.6, let alone Django 2.0. Even if you changed that so that Django wasn't downgraded, the two libraries aren't going to work together.